# Find all the integer pairs $(x, y)$ which satisfy the equation $x^5-y^5=16xy$

Tags: number-theory, inequality, contest-math, problem-solving, intuition

I just came across the following question:

> Find all the integer pairs $(x, y)$ which satisfy the equation $x^5-y^5=16xy$

I solved it as follows:

$x=y=0$ obvious solution. If $xy\neq0$, let $d=gcd(x, y)$ and we write $x=da$, $y=db$, $a, b\in \Bbb{Z}$ with $(a, b)=1$. Then, the given equation is:
$$d^3a^5-d^3b^5=16ab$$
So, by the above equation, $a$ divides $d^3b^5$ and hence $a$ divides $d^3$. Similarly $b$ divides $d^3$. Since $(a, b)=1$  we have that $ab$ divides $d^3$, so $d^3=abr$ with $r\in \Bbb{Z}$. Then the above equation becomes $abra^5-abrb^5=16ab$, so $r(a^5-b^5)=16$.

Hence, the difference $a^5-b^5$ must divide $16$. If $|(a^5-b^5)|\le2$ we have that $(x, y)=(-2, 2)$ is a solution. Otherwise $$|a^5-b^5|=|(x+1)^5-b^5|\ge |(x+1)^5-x^5|=|5x^4+10x^3+10x^2+5x+1|\ge31$$ which is impossible.

So only solutions are $(x, y)=(0, 0)$ or $(-2, 2)$.

I believe that this solution is not at all intuitive nor simple. Could you please post a more intuitive and simple solution where you are explaining your intuition on every step?

Comment: It may not have been intuitive (according to you) but it is very beautiful, nevertheless.

Comment: This is a really nice solution and one I would not have thought of myself. Diophantine equations are rarely intuitive. Well done on your nice solution.

Comment: Since you have $x,y$ in all the terms in the equation, it is always useful to look at the GCD, since you have no constant terms, i.e. $x$ or $y$ in all the terms, so some power ($1$ or more) of the GCD will move away from both sides, so the number of prime factors on all sides will decrease, which might lead to easier equations. Other than that, any intuition is only bought from problem solving. Neatly done! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all,if $x=y$ then $x=y=0$ which does work. So,now assume $x \not =y$. Again if one of them is $0$, other one has to be also. So,from now on also assume that none of them is $0$

$\textbf{Case 1:}$ $x,y$ both are positive.
Then $(x-y)(x^4+x^3y+x^2y^2+xy^3+y^4)=16xy$

since obviously $x >y$,if $x \ge 3$ we have $x^4+x^3y \ge 9x^2+9xy \ge 9xy+9xy=18xy$.So, $x \le 2$So,only a few case to check.

$\textbf{Case 2:}$ Both are negative gives the same equation with $x,y$ swapped.

$\textbf{Case 3:}$ $x$ negative but $y$ positive would give $x^5+y^5=16xy$ by substituting
$x=-x$ to make things easier to work with.
Here a simple AM-GM can be applied to show that $16xy \ge 2x^{5/2}y^{5/2} \implies 8 \ge (xy)^{3/2} \ge xy$. So, a very small number of cases to check. We will find the solution $(2,2)$ which in turns means $(-2,2)$ is a solution to the original equation.

Last case is only $y$ is negative but that's obviously impossible.

Hence $(0,0)$ and $(-2,2)$
are the only possible pairs satisfying the given relation

Answer (score 2):

The following is neither intuitive nor simple, but it does give a different approach to the proof.

If $xy\not=0$, let $p$ be an odd prime and write $x=p^ru$ and $y=p^sv$ with $p\not\mid uv$.  From $p^{5r}u^5-p^{5s}v^5=16uvp^{r+s}$, we see we cannot have $r=s\not=0$, so we either have $5r=r+s$ or $5s=r+s$. This means that we can write $x$ and $y$ in the form $x=2^aA^4B$ and $y=2^bAB^4$ with $A$ and $B$ relatively prime odd numbers. But we now have $2^{5a}A^{20}B^5-2^{5b}A^5B^{20}=2^{a+b+4}A^5B^5$, from which we obtain

$$2^{5a}A^{15}-2^{5b}B^{15}=2^{a+b+4}$$

so we must now have $a=b$ (since otherwise the left hand side factors into a power of $2$ times an odd number not equal to $1$), which implies $2^{5a}(A^{15}+B^{15})=2^{2a+4}$, or

$$2^{3a}(A^{15}-B^{15})=2^4$$

The only $15$th powers of odd numbers that differ by a small power of $2$ come from $A=1$ and $B=-1$, so the only solution with $xy\not=0$ is $x=-2$ and $y=2$.